# In my application Popup blocked is coming when I am using targent as_blank

Tags: javascript, html

`target="_blank" not working in my application and here is my fiddle`[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfhosrtc/). But it works fine here and when I am using this in my application popup blocked alert is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is on purpose, built-in protection by the browser. For a browser to let any website just fire off as many .click()'s as they want, you could see how a potential malicious website could attempt to open hundreds of tabs and throw the user's browser into a frenzy. Thus most browsers protect the user from non-user-initiated window/tab opens.

NOTE: Some browsers may behave differently, and some user settings could potentially alter this behavior. There's probably no guarantee.

If you remove the target, it would navigate them away from that one page, but it would work.

Nice circle animation btw!